# react import error in visual studio code, it automatically added long path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image: react import error in visual studio code]

[image: react Failed to compile]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'C:/Users/appsmaster/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/2.9/node_modules/@types/prop-types'
```

**Error:**

> ./src/components/footer/index.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/appsmaster/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/2.9/node_modules/@types/prop-types' in

Comment: Just write `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` instead.

Comment: thats the error result, original code : import PropTypes from 'prop-types'  and it happend automaticlly when I save or restart it,

Comment: I experience the same error with my React import.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing / re-installing
`npm install --save prop-types` 
and check if the error is persistent

Comment: Actually this happened several times before n not only for prop-types  but some others packages, n I dont know whats the problem, but thanks for the suggestions, Im trying to re-install the dependencies, hope this can fix it,